# Set the Calendar to a specific date?

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

I want to set a reminder with notification on a specific date. Then I am using AlarmManager with NotificationManager currently. When I set selected date from dateDialog, the reminder is working. How can I put calendar value on alarm set with fixed time? I get the current date and time from this :

```
Calendar calendar =  Calendar.getInstance();
```

and then I can set the calendar manually like below and it's working:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 13);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 7);
calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,2015);
long when = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
```

But my question is how can I set the calendar to tomorrow and 9:00 AM or set the calendar exactly to a particular month (or year) later from the current date? I mean something like this :

```
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

but it does not work.

Comment: What means  `but it does not work`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Joda-Time

**UPDATE:** The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Try using a better date-time library, such as Joda-Time.

In Joda-Time you can change the date while keeping the time of day. Or, vice-versa, keep the time of day while keeping the date.

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
DateTime todayNoon = now.withTime( 12, 0, 0, 0 ) ;
DateTime midMarchSameYearSameTimeAsNow = now.withDate(  now.getYear(), DateTimeConstants.MARCH, 15 );
DateTime tomorrowSameTime = now.plusDays( 1 );
```

Answer (score 5):

For me this works just fine on the desktop, <s>couldn't test it on Android though</s>.

**Update:** just tested this on my Android phone using AIDE, getting the exact same results.

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class CalendarTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        System.out.println(calendar.getTimeInMillis() + " -> " + calendar.getTime());

        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 13);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 7);
        calendar.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 9);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);

        System.out.println(calendar.getTimeInMillis() + " -> " + calendar.getTime());

        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        calendar.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);

        System.out.println(calendar.getTimeInMillis() + " -> " + calendar.getTime());
    }
```

For this test my output is just what you would expect:

```
1420705649927 -> Thu Jan 08 09:27:29 CET 2015
1420783980927 -> Fri Jan 09 07:13:00 CET 2015
1452406380927 -> Sun Jan 10 07:13:00 CET 2016
```

Comment: will you please answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253122/get-previous-next-day-date-on-button-press-after-getting-date-from-previous-acti

Answer (score 0):

To add an hour by example, you can do something like this :

```
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.of(
    LocalDate.of( 2015 , Month.JANUARY , 8 ) ,
    LocalTime.of( 7 , 13 , 0 ) ,
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) 
)
.toInstant()
.toEpochMilli()
```

> 1420697580000

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes. *So* much easier and cleaner now.

Your code is ambiguous, as you do not address the crucial issue of time zone. As you did not specify a time zone explicitly, your JVM’s current default time zone will be applied implicitly. I strongly recommend *always* specifying your desired/expected time zone.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2015 , Month.JANUARY , 8 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 7 , 13 , 0 ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

You could use a combo factor method, alternatively.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( 2015 , Month.JANUARY , 8 , 7 , 13 , 0 , 0 , ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) ;
```

I generally recommend against tracking date-time as a count-from-epoch. But it seems to be requirement in your case.

First we can extract a `Instant`, a moment in UTC. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Convert from a zoned value to a UTC value.
```

You can then ask for the count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Beware of possible data loss, as any microseconds or nanoseconds in the `Instant` will be ignored when reporting mere milliseconds.

```
long millis = instant.toEpochMilli() ;  // Count of milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).