# I wanted to convert this string into calendar object of the specific date, but all it does is giving me the current date

Tags: java, string, date, calendar, simpledateformat

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

        String startDateStr = stripQuotes("2017/08/01 15:18:01"); 

                    Date startDateDate; 
                    Calendar startDate = null;
                    try {
                        startDateDate = dateFormat.parse(startDateStr)
                        startDate = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                        startDate.setTime(startDateDate);               
                    } catch (ParseException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(AttendanceController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }


Honey honey1 = new Honey(1,"ok","ok2",startDate);
```

Comment: Works fine for me - what does `stripQuotes` do?  You should also consider using the newer Java Timer API available in Java 8 ... or just about any other date/time API (like JodaTime)

Comment: IMHO you shouldn’t bother with the long outdated classes `SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar` and `Date`. `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API also known as JSR-310, is so much nicer to work with. You can use it in Java 6 and later (in Java 6 and 7 through the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/)).

Comment: I see no way your code could produce a `startDate` here in November except on a computer with the clock set three months off. Could you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please?

Comment: Sorry guys, it seems that the specific code works perfectly. On the other hand, i was using streams in another method by just giving the (startdate)/ variable the current date again. I had to use the debugger to get it sorted. Thanks a lot for your feedback, Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran this code and works fine for me. `startDate.getTime()` returns `Tue Aug 01 15:18:01 PDT 2017`, which is as expected.
Only thing is you're missing a semicolon at the end of line `startDateDate = dateFormat.parse(startDateStr)`.

This might also help you: [Set the Calendar to a specific date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835229/set-the-calendar-to-a-specific-date)

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse( 
    "2017/08/01 15:18:01" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" , Locale.US )
).atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC )
```

## Legacy classes

As others stated, your code should be working as expected.

```
// Old outmoded way using troublesome legacy classes.
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse( input ) ;
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance() ;
cal.setTime( date ) ;
System.out.println( "date.toString(): " + date  ) ;
```

You can see that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/H5Ef9z).

> date.toString(): Tue Aug 01 15:18:01 GMT 2017

You have a bigger problem. You are using terribly troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Avoid these old classes like the Plague.

### ISO 8601

By the way, you are using a less-than-optimal format for representing a date-time as a String. Instead use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. The java.time classes use the ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings. You can see so in next example.

And specify a time zone where one is intended. Omitting the offset or zone leads to confusion, errors, and pain.

## java.time

Let’s rewrite that code the modern way.

```
// New modern way in Java 8 and later.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" , Locale.US ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

Your example code in the Questions suggests the date-time represented by the input string was intended to represent a moment in UTC (an offset-from-UTC of zero). The `LocalDateTime` object we have above has no zone or offset, and so does *not* represent a point on the timeline. This object has no definite meaning until you assign an offset/zone.

```
// If we assume this date-time was meant to be UTC.
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
System.out.println( "odt.toString(): " + odt ) ;
```

You can see that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/H5Ef9z).

> odt.toString(): 2017-08-01T15:18:01Z